# How to style odd rows in a table in this vue.js example?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add style to every odd number of rows in a table.  But the example below fails.

```
template: `
<div container>
  <h3>test title</h3>
  <table :style="overviewStyle">
  <div :class="emptyDiv" v-for="item in testlist">
   <tr>
      <td :style="{'tdStyle': index % 2 === 0, 'tdGray': index % 2 !== 0 }">[[ item.result ]]</td>
   </tr>
  </div>
  </table>
</div>
`,

computed: {
  tdStyle() {
    return {
        'border': '1px solid #C0C0C0',
        'padding': '8px',
    };
  },
  tdGray() {
    return {
        'background-color': gray,
    };
  },
```

What's interesting to me is this example works with class.

```
<td :class="{'tdStyle': index % 2 === 0, 'tdGray': index % 2 !== 0 }">[[ item.result ]]</td>
```

So works with :class but not :style.

If there is not an easier solution, is there a way I can move this logic into a function and then call the function to color odd rows?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot place a div element where you have it in the table.

Comment: yea i'll correct later ty - right now im focused on how to find and style odd num of rows using vue.js

Comment: No, you need to correct it now. It may be a source of problems now or later. Your question may be closed for this reason. Invalid HTML is an error. We don't work with incorrect markup.

Comment: In addition to @Rob's comments, please note you can use `<template>` instead of `<div>` which will apply your logic **without** adding a DOM element wrapper around the contents, resulting in valid HTML markup for your case. However, `:class` needs to be moved on the inner `<tr>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in pure CSS. There is absolutely no reason to put this in conditional code or JavaScript, which makes it much harder to maintain. Vue has a way to combine HTML templates, JSS and CSS into components but I'm no expert on that aspect.

```css
.zebra tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eee;
}
.zebra tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="zebra">
  <tr><td>foo
  <tr><td>bar
  <tr><td>baz
  <tr><td>fizz
  <tr><td>buzz
</table>
```

As to specifically why your code didn't work, vue uses `:class` to add classes conditionally. When passing a JavaScript object to `:class`, each key is understood as a class name, which is present if its value is true.

The `:style` attribute has a different special behavior where each key of the object passed is a CSS attribute. This is useful if, for example, you want to always set an attribute on an element, but its value is conditional.

Your code uses `:style` with things that aren't CSS attributes.

```
<td :style="{'tdStyle': index % 2 === 0, 'tdGray': index % 2 !== 0 }">
```

If you wanted to use it without setting up a CSS class, you'd need to do something like this. It's been a while since I haven't done vue though, and I would strongly advise against putting this kind of logic in HTML attributes.

```
<td :style="{'background': index % 2 === 0 ? '#eee' : '#ccc' }">
```

Finally, your code is not even valid HTML with a div inside a table, which most certainly will cause issues as the browser doesn't know where to put the div and where to put the tbody.

Comment: Yes I would like to use a solution like this, but I am trying to encapsulate my css in the vue.js component itself (my entire example is a vue.js component)

Comment: Look into using Vue CLI / Webpack and single file components (SFC).  https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: I am trying to use the last solution you provided but it turns all my rows and columns gray.

Comment: ""Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.""

Comment: @david  *"all my rows and columns gray"* put the dynamic `:style` on `<tr>` not `<td>`. *"Property or method "index" is not defined.."* add the `index` on the loop: `v-for="(item, index) in testlist"`

Answer (score 1):

While as the previous answer mentioned, yes you could probably do this using pure CSS (better IMO too), just wanted to answer your question on why `class` binding works but `style` does not.

If you look at the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), you will see that your syntax for style is not correct. For class, what you have is correct and it should look like this:

```
<div :class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
```

However, for binding style, you actually have to return the CSS styles as an object:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>
```

So in your scenario, the style object becomes this (assuming on an even index):

```
{
  tdStyle: true,
  tdGrey: false
}
```

This is obviously not valid CSS. If you want to actually put the values of the functions, I suggest you use the spread operator for object destructuring in ES6, and for a cleaner code, use the JS ternary operator as well:

```
<td :style="{ index % 2 === 0 ? ...tdStyle : ...tdGray }">
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to add any more styles, you can omit the object syntax completely and use this:

```
<td :style="index % 2 === 0 ? tdStyle : tdGray">
```

In here, what basically happens is the binding says "if index is even, then return the result of `tdStyle` function, else return the result of `tdGray` function".

But of course as mentioned just CSS is the superior solution here. If you really want add some special styling that CSS can't help with, you are still better off using `class` binding instead of `style`, that way your CSS can live inside the `style` tag of your component:

```
<td :class="index % 2 === 0 ? 'tdStyle' : 'tdGray'">
```